# default Exception in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using GAE for my backend. I would like to set something like "default exception" for each Cloud Endpoint method. In other words if the method throws some Exception I don't expect (this Exception is not listed in method signature in throws), the thrown Exception can contain some information about my database ... This information can be exploited by an attacker. This issue is also known as "Improper error handling" listed in OWASP 10 [[1]](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2009/12/the-best-c-interview-question-ever.html). Therefore I would like to catch such Exceptions and throw a default custom Exception instead of it.
In practice:
This code is a possible "hard coded" solution for my problem. But it's too much writing for many cloud endpoint methods. So I am asking if there is some pattern, or some setting in some .xml of GAE which solves my problem in a simpler way.

```
public User insertUser(User user) throws ExceptionA, ExceptionB, ExceptionC, DefaultException 
//I am expecting that insertUser can throw ExceptionA, ExceptionB, ExceptionC
{
    try {

    }
    catch (ExceptionA e1) {
         throw new ExceptionA(e1.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ExceptionB e2) {
         throw new ExceptionB(e2.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ExceptionC e3) {
         throw new ExceptionC(e2.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e4) {
         /*This Exception can contain some exploitable information*/
         throw new DefaultException("Something went wrong");
    }
    finally {

    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and with some new knowledge I am returning to my question.
This is possible using the [Spring MVC exception handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes).

Following the tutorial I can create a GlobalExceptionHandler, which enables to return the concrete HTTP value in case an exception is thrown in some of the endpoint methods.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(corresponding HTTP return value) 
    @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
    public void handleException() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```